# How to speed up complex/difficult data filtering in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very large data set that has the below indices and column headers.

```
+------+------------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------+------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+--------------------------+
|      | count: interaction_eis | count: interaction_eis_reply | count: interaction_match | count: interaction_single_message_ | count: interaction_single_message_1 | count: interaction_yes | dc(uid): interaction_eis | dc(uid): interaction_eis_reply | dc(uid): interaction_match | dc(uid): interaction_single_message_ | dc(uid): interaction_single_message_1 | dc(uid): interaction_yes |
+------+------------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------+------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+--------------------------+
| uid  |                        |                              |                          |                                    |                                     |                        |                          |                                |                            |                                      |                                       |                          |
| 38   |                     36 |                            0 |                        0 |                                 14 |                                   0 |                    163 |                        1 |                              0 |                          0 |                                    1 |                                     0 |                        1 |
| 66   |                     63 |                            0 |                        0 |                                  0 |                                   0 |                      0 |                        1 |                              0 |                          0 |                                    0 |                                     0 |                        0 |
| 1466 |                      0 |                            0 |                        0 |                                  0 |                                   0 |                      1 |                        0 |                              0 |                          0 |                                    0 |                                     0 |                        1 |
| 1709 |                     51 |                            0 |                        0 |                                  1 |                                   0 |                      9 |                        1 |                              0 |                          0 |                                    1 |                                     0 |                        1 |
| 1844 |                     66 |                            0 |                        1 |                                  3 |                                   1 |                     17 |                        1 |                              0 |                          1 |                                    1 |                                     1 |                        1 |
+------+------------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------+------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+--------------------------+
```

I am attempting to group UIDs by type of interaction received, where if a user only has one certain type of interaction they will ONLY be grouped with other users who only have that specific type of interaction.

To do this I started by taking all of the dc(uid) columns which only have `1` "hit" per interaction type and a `0` if the interaction type never happened and aggregating them into groups row by row like this:

```
cols = [i for i in list(all_f_rm.columns) if i[0]=="d"]

def aggregate(row):
    key = ""
    for i in cols:
        key+=str(row[i])

    if key not in results:
        results[key] = []
    results[key].append(row.name)

results = {}
all_f_rm.apply(aggregate, axis=1)
```

`results.keys()` is all of the potential interaction type combinations (35 of them) and the value for each key is every index (UID) that belongs to that combination.  It looks like this:
`{'001101': [141168, 153845, 172598, 254401, 448276,...`

Next, I made a function to filter out all of the non matching rows for each combination/key:

```
def tableFor(key):
    return all_f_rm[all_f_rm.apply(lambda row: row.name in results[key], axis=1)]
```

And `tableFor('001101')` displays the exact DataFrame that I want.

My problem is this that I wrote a list comprehension to loop through all 35 combinations like this `[tableFor(x) for x in results.keys()]` but it is taking forever (1+ hrs and hasn't finished) and I need to perform this on 5 more data sets.  Is there a more efficient way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can do what you want as a `groupby`.  Constructing a toy dataframe like yours:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"uid": np.arange(10**6)})
for col in range(6):
    df["dc{}".format(col)] = np.random.randint(0,2,len(df))
```

We can group by the columns of interest and get the associated id numbers very rapidly:

```
>>> dcs = [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith("dc")]
>>> df.groupby(dcs)["uid"].unique()
dc0  dc1  dc2  dc3  dc4  dc5
0    0    0    0    0    0      [302, 357, 383, 474, 526, 614, 802, 812, 865, ...
                         1      [7, 96, 190, 220, 405, 453, 534, 598, 606, 866...
                    1    0      [16, 209, 289, 355, 430, 620, 634, 736, 780, 7...
                         1      [9, 79, 166, 268, 408, 434, 435, 447, 572, 749...
               1    0    0      [60, 120, 196, 222, 238, 346, 426, 486, 536, 5...
                         1      [2, 53, 228, 264, 315, 517, 557, 621, 626, 630...
                    1    0      [42, 124, 287, 292, 300, 338, 341, 350, 500, 5...
                         1      [33, 95, 140, 192, 225, 282, 328, 339, 365, 44...
          1    0    0    0      [1, 59, 108, 134, 506, 551, 781, 823, 836, 861...
                         1      [149, 215, 380, 394, 436, 482, 570, 600, 631, ...
                    1    0      [77, 133, 247, 333, 374, 782, 809, 892, 1096, ...
                         1      [14, 275, 312, 326, 343, 444, 569, 692, 770, 7...
               1    0    0      [69, 104, 143, 404, 431, 468, 636, 639, 657, 7...
                         1      [178, 224, 367, 402, 664, 666, 739, 807, 871, ...
[...]
```

If you'd prefer the associated groups instead, you can get a list or a dictionary from this as well, rather than simply pulling out the indices:

```
>>> groups = list(df.groupby(dcs, as_index=False))
>>> print(groups[0][0])
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
>>> print(groups[0][1])
           uid  dc0  dc1  dc2  dc3  dc4  dc5
302        302    0    0    0    0    0    0
357        357    0    0    0    0    0    0
383        383    0    0    0    0    0    0
[...]
999730  999730    0    0    0    0    0    0
999945  999945    0    0    0    0    0    0
999971  999971    0    0    0    0    0    0

[15357 rows x 7 columns]
```

and so on.

Comment: Thanks for this.  It is certainly a more elegant way of doing the first portion of my program.  However, I think the slowness is coming from iterating over every row in the large data frame 35 times (one time for each of the combinations) to filter for the new dataframes.  Do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: Now that I'm thinking about it... using the groupby will allow me to perform operations on the groups with out doing all of the filtering business, right?

Comment: As near as I can tell, it does *both*; your "new dataframes" are simply the dataframes associated with the groups, e.g. the `groups[0][1]` I showed.   Your approach is slow for several reasons, but probably the single slowest (assuming your dataframe is very large) is that your `row.name in results[key]` is testing membership in a list, and that's O(N); if you made it a set, it would be fast*er*, though still not fast.

Comment: Got it, right this makes so much more sense.  One last question if I may.  In my data set I have the `count` columns and the `dc(uid)` columns.  Is it possible to perform your groupby on just the `dc(uid)` columns while still returning the all columns?

Comment: @Meepl: this already will!  The `dcs` list I built is the list of dc columns I wanted to groupby on -- note that there's a `uid` column in `groups[0][1]` even though I didn't mention it.

Comment: I'd recommend reading through the [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) part of the tutorial.  It'll help you get a sense for the split-apply-combine pattern.

Comment: You used the column of `uid` for this `pre_purch_m.groupby(dcs)["uid"].unique()` but for me it is my index.  I tried `pre_purch_m.groupby(dcs)[pre_purch_m.index].unique()` but I got a `KeyError`

Comment: If it's your index, you can make it a column by `pre_purch_m = pre_purch_m.reset_index()`.